# Using the same array of objects in many partial classes(pages) in a windows phone app

Tags: c#, class, oop, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a windows phone 8.1 app , I am trying to assign a value to a class method in a different partial class(page) but the debugging error is that object has null reference , or , does not exit !

here is my code , first I declared the class in the Main Page :

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public class MyClass
    {

        public static MyClass[] object = new MyClass[4];

        MyClass()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                object[i] = new MyClass();

            }
        }

        public string name = null;

    }
    // Rest of the Main Page Code
}
```

Then I want to use the same array of objects class in another page , so I did this :

```
public partial class EnterPlayersNames : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public EnterPlayersNames()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PhoneApp.MainPage.MyClass.object[0].name = Player1Name.Text;
    }

}
```

If anybody could help thankfully ..

Answer (score 0):

"object" is a reserved word in C#, rename your static variable to something else and this should work just fine.

```
public static MyClass[] object = new MyClass[4];
```

Also because it's Static... you don't need to reference any particular instance of MyClass to get that property. Just NameSpace.MyClass.StaticObjectName will do.

Comment: No, I used the word "object" here as an exemple , actually in my project I did :
Table[] Player = new Table[4]